# Concave continous function with special property implies that is strictly increasing?

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, control-theory, monotone-functions

I have the following problem. Let $\rho(s)\geq 0$ for all $s\geq 0$ be a continuous concave function, satisfying $\rho(s)\geq\rho_1(s)$ for all $s>0$, where $\rho_1$ is a strictly increasing and positive function (not necessarily continuous). Does it follow that $\rho$ is also strictly increasing?

My guess is that this is the case, otherwise there would exist $s'>0$ such that $\rho_1(s)>\rho(s)$, arriving at a contradiction. However, the existence of this $s'$ is not evident to me. If anyone could guide me towards an answer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If by concave downwards you don't mean concave and decreasing, then remove the word "downwards", as it will only cause confusion.

Comment: I agree with you, but sometimes people say concave downwards/upwards to differentiate between concave and convex, will edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: What about $$\rho(s)=\min\{s,1\}$$ and $$\rho_1(s)=\min\{s/2, 1/2-e^{-s}/4\}.$$

Comment: To see that those are concave, you can use the fact that the minimum of concave functions is concave https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507863/concavity-of-max-of-two-concave-functions

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice counterexample. Would be interesting to find an example where $\rho$ is strictly concave, will give it some thouhgt

Comment: @SergioGarciaCastro It might be a good idea for you to write this up as an answer including all the details I skipped. That might help the next person

Comment: If the function is not strictly monotone, then it won't be strictly concave. You'll have some plateau.